# How to select from a checkbox using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have this website: https://magiceden.io/marketplace/primates. On the website there's a default option of "Recently listed". How can I use java selenium to change that from the checklist to "price: low to high"? [image]

Comment: Please provide html code the checkbox so that we can provide you same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is quite simple and can be done simply using the native driver properties without over complicating it with using Javascript, Actions or Scroll.**

You are facing a problem because the element you are trying to locate is called an "*svg element*" so it will not support standard xpath format. So rather than focusing on the checkbox, pin-point the non svg element instead (the div class the element is in).

The code will then look like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

    class App {
        public static WebDriver driver;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // set your driver here
            ...

            // select checkbox
            driver.get("https://magiceden.io/marketplace/primates");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Recently Listed']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Price: Low to high']")).click();
        }
    }
```

**The final result will look like this:**

[[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

I can see the element **Recently listed** is inside the `shadow-root` so you have use `javascript` executor here.

***Solution***

```
        driver.get("https://magiceden.io/marketplace/primates");

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);

        action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform();

        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

        WebElement search_box = (WebElement) jse.executeScript("return document.querySelector(\"#content > div.tw-w-full.tw-py-0.sm\\\\:tw-mt-0 > div.tw-flex.tw-relative > div.tw-flex-auto.tw-max-w-full.tw-pt-0 > div.tw-flex.tw-w-full.tw-flex-col.lg\\\\:tw-flex-row.tw-flex-nowrap.lg\\\\:tw-flex-wrap.tw-box-border.tw-min-h-\\\\[52px\\\\].tw-border-0.tw-border-solid.tw-border-gray-300.tw-border-b.tw-px-5.tw-py-0\\\\.5.xl\\\\:tw-sticky.xl\\\\:tw-top-\\\\[79px\\\\].tw-z-10.tw-bg-gray-100 > div.tw-flex.tw-items-center.tw-flex-grow.tw-justify-center.lg\\\\:tw-justify-end > div.me-dropdown-container.lg\\\\:tw-max-w-\\\\[260px\\\\].tw-min-w-\\\\[180px\\\\].tw-flex-grow.tw-text-sm > div.cursor-pointer.position-relative > input\")");

        String js = "arguments[0].click();";

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, search_box);
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[normalize-space()='Price: Low to high']")).click();
```

***Import***

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
```

*Hope this will solve you issue.*

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later. Btw what does the line with action.sendkeys() do here?

Comment: Please accept the answer if this solve your question, this `action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).build().perform();` will scroll down the page